# I receive a PHP warning notice only on localhost

Tags: php, session

I receive a PHP warning:

```
"Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()".
```

This happens only on the localhost and not on the server.

The same file exists on server and localhost.

Why is there a variation of results ?

Here is my Code :

```
<?php session_start ();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>BookMyFilms - Register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
</html>
<?php
$username = $_POST ['username'];
$_SESSION ['user'] = $username;
require ('includes/header.php');
require ('includes/db.php');
require ('includes/common.php');
Register ();
require ('includes/footer.php');?>
```

Comment: Your server probably has notices turned off.

Comment: ...or the stack running on your local machine may have your php.ini configured with [`session.auto_start`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Servers are usually configured in a "Production" environment, which don't print notices and warnings.
For the other problem, you probably have another `session_start` in one of your next includes.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Warning notices must have been turned off on your live server. Well, you can enable it like

```
error_reporting(E_NOTICE);
```

---

The **main issue** is you must be having `session_start();` in any of these files and that's why you get the notice...

```
require ('includes/header.php');
require ('includes/db.php');
require ('includes/common.php');
require ('includes/footer.php');?>
```

Try checking those files for `session_start();` occurence.. if so.. comment it off , since you have already started in the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
<?php session_start ();?>
```

to

```
<?php @session_start ();?>
```

and you are done..! you will not get notice on any server..

Comment: i suggest that it is more useful to find the fault rather than just suppressing messages. The 'notices' are often clues about other issues with the code.

Comment: "la la la I can't hear you" is a bad approach to error handling.